# Package does not exist - android/java

Tags: java, unit-testing, android-studio, import, package

I ran into this weird problem that happens when i try to run a unit test for one of my app classes: "package does not exist".

If i run the app i get the same error, but if i press "run" again it compiles and works just fine, i have also made another unit test for another class and the same process repeats i run it the first time, get the error, run it again and it compiles. But for some reason when i run this new unit test in particular i get the same error and does not compile.

Here is the particular code generating the error:

```
package chess_game;
import org.junit.Test;
import pieces.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
public class GameTest {
    @Test
    public void enPassantLegalMoves(){

        ...

        Piece bking = new King(PieceColour.BLACK);
        bd[3][2].setPiece(bking);

        Piece bpawn = new Pawn(PieceColour.BLACK);
        bpawn.setHasMovedAlready(true);
        bd[4][4].setPiece(bpawn);

        Piece wking = new King(PieceColour.WHITE);
        bd[7][4].setPiece(wking);

        Piece wpawn = new Pawn(PieceColour.WHITE);
        wpawn.setHasMovedAlready(true);
        bd[4][3].setPiece(wpawn);

        ...
    }
}
```

[image] [image: The error]

**Note:** I dont know if its relevant but i am using android studio and the IDE doesn`t give any warnings besided the compiling error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wich JUnit you use

Comment: Check this doc this can help you https://developer.android.com/training/testing/

Comment: And this is more specific for you https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests

Comment: @crammeur i am using JUnit4. I dont know if it matters but in this test in particular i am only testing "normal java" and nothing related to android.

Comment: I see you package structure and I think is this cause the problem because they can't access the other package.

Comment: @crammeur should i move my pieces package?

Comment: Try to put the package `pieces` in your `chess_game` package. Not `chess_game (test)`

Comment: @crammeur yeah that solved the problem, no more error. If you want to make that an answer i will mark it as correct. thanks

Comment: Thank to you to improve my point too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is the project structure.

you need to put your package `pieces` in the `chess_game` package. Not in `chess_game (test)`